# How can I test if a waitable timer is already active?

Tags: winapi, timer

I'm using a [waitable timer object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/waitable-timer-objects) and would like to start it via [`SetWaitableTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer) *unless* the timer is already running. The `SetWaitableTimer` explains that

> If the timer is already active when you call SetWaitableTimer, the timer is stopped, then it is reactivated.

Hence, I'm currently maintaining a flag indicating whether the timer is active. Alas, keeping it in sync with various `SetWaitableTimer` and [`CancelWaitableTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-cancelwaitabletimer) calls is a bit tedious. Is there maybe a better way to do it than manual bookkeeping?

Comment: Is it manual reset? Periodical?

Comment: There is no function in the Win32 API to check if a waitable timer is already active. You have to keep track of that manually in your own code when you call `SetWaitableTimer()`, which you are already doing. To make the job easier, simply wrap the timer in a class that does its own bookkeeping, then pass that class around as needed.

Comment: [When the specified due time arrives, the timer becomes inactive.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setwaitabletimer)  Otherwise it is active. (Timers are initially inactive.) You can determine the status via completion routine that is application-defined function of type PTIMERAPCROUTINE to be executed when the timer is signaled.

Comment: @Anders It is a periodical timer (i.e. I don't wait on the timer handle to be signalled but use a completion routine). It's currently a manual-reset timer.

Comment: Did you try WaitForSingleObject with a 0 timeout to test the signal state? Not sure if it works when using IOCR.

Comment: @Anders I think `WaitForSingleObject` will tell me if the timer fired. What I'm interested in is whether it is 'active' in the sense of `SetWaitableTimer` having been called but the timer not having fired yet.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I misunderstood then. The function you are after does probably not exist but you can try looking for undocumented functions in ntdll and/or see if WinDbg is able to spit out useful information about these timers.